# How to use a generic factory for generic type without warnings?

Tags: java, generics, factory

I have a factory method like

```
public static <T> Something<T> create(Class<T> clazz) {
    return new Something<T>(clazz);
}
```

taking a `Class` argument. When I use it like in

```
Something<String> something1 = Something.create(String.class);
```

everything is fine. But for

```
Something<List> something2 = Something.create(List.class);
```

I get a warning I can't get rid of. For whatever I try I get a warning or an error.

Is there anything I could do besides `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`?

Actually, I'd like to get

```
Something<List<?>> something2 = Something.create(List.class);
```

which I can't get without two casts and a warning. I'm using eclipse 3.5.2.

Comment: FYI, Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) has been out for a while now.

Comment: Thx, I installed it now. The behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static public <A, B extends A> Class<B> rawcast(Class<A> clazz)
{ 
    return (Class<B>)clazz; 
}

void test()
{
    Class<List<?>> clazz = rawcast(List.class);

    Something<List<?>> something2 = Something.create(clazz);
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea, unfortunately single `rawcast` is not enough as there is `Map<K, V>` and probably some classes with more type parameters. I'm afraid, it won't get any better and accept your answer.

Comment: @maaartinus that should be fine: `Class<Map<String,Int>> clazz = rawcast(Map.class)`

Comment: You're right, I completely overlooked that the `<B>` goes to `Class` and not to the List/Map.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to provide the method with a dummy instance of the class you would like to use for the generic parameter. E.g.:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T a) {
   return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

Comment: Actually, I want exactly `List<?>`. Moreover, elsewhere I need it for classes which I can not or don't want to instantiate.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible in Java. Thanks to type erasure and some other nasty stuff in how Java generics are implemented because of backward compatibility with Java 1.4.